# Printing first and last match in file

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

Is there a cleaner solution to the following?

```
grep INFO messages | head -1
grep INFO messages | tail -1
```

The length of INFO or messages is random.

Comment: What should the output look like if INFO does not occur in messages or only occurs once? Edit your question to show sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try:

```
grep INFO messages | sed -n '1p;$p'
```

grep - will search for pattern from messages file
sed -n '1p;$p' - will print first (1p) and last($p) line

Comment: Thank you so much to you all, this one hit the spot for my task and I feel the others will help with keeping it safe.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `-m` to establish how many matches you want:

For the first:

```
grep -m1 "INFO" messages
```

For the last, let's print the file backwards with `tac` and then use the same logic:

```
tac messages | grep -m1 "INFO"
```

This way, you avoid processing the whole file twice: you will just process it until a match is found.

---

From `man grep`:

> -m NUM, --max-count=NUM
>
> Stop reading a file after NUM matching lines.  If the input is 
>   standard  input  from  a  regular  file,  and  NUM matching lines are
>   output, grep ensures that the standard input is positioned to just
>   after the last matching line before exiting, regardless of the
>   presence of trailing context lines.  This enables a calling process to
>   resume  a search.   When grep stops after NUM matching lines, it
>   outputs any trailing context lines.  When the -c or --count option is
>   also used, grep does not output a count greater than NUM.  When the -v
>   or --invert-match option is  also used, grep stops after outputting
>   NUM non-matching lines.

`man tac`:

> tac - concatenate and print files in reverse

Answer (score 2):

This may be what you want:

```
awk '/INFO/{f[++c]=$0} END{ if (c>0) print f[1] ORS f[c] }' messages
```

or:

```
awk '/INFO/{f[++c]=$0} END{ if (c>0) print f[1]; if (c>1) print f[c] }' messages
```

but without sample input and expected output it's a guess.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could use awk:

```
awk '/INFO/{a[++i]=$0}END{print a[1];print a[i]}' messages
```

This will store every match in an array, which could be an issue for memory consumption if there are very many matches. An alternative would be to only store the first and the most recent:

```
awk '/INFO/{a[++i>2?2:i]=$0}END{print a[1];print a[2]}' messages
```

Or as Etan has suggested (thanks):

```
awk '/INFO/{a=$0}a&&!i++{print}END{if(a)print a}' messages
```

The advantage to this one is that if there are no matches, nothing will be printed.

Comment: No need to store all the lines for this. Just print the first and store the most recent. `'/kernel/{a=$0}a&&!i{print;i=1}END{print a}'`

Comment: Good point, I was just thinking that myself and came up with a different solution. I've included yours as well, thanks.

Comment: Maybe it is good to consider the case when there is just one match (or none), like Ed Morton does. Anyway, +1 for the broad set of options :)

Comment: @fedorqui it's a potential issue but I feel like I'd be copying now!

Comment: Haha I understand the feeling: many good answers appearing and then being kind of "trapped" to improve it because it will be so similar to the others. It happens often!