# Print first and last matching 0 in column

Tags: awk

I have this file :

```
chr1    1       1
chr1    2       5
chr1    3       0
chr1    4       0
chr1    5       0
chr1    6       3
chr1    7       4
chr1    8       0
chr1    9       0
chr1    10      6
```

I need to output :

```
chr1    3       0
chr1    5       0
chr1    8       0
chr1    9       0
```

I would like to print the first and last line when the 0 value is found in the third column. Even if there is only one 0 value, not necessarily a range of O.

I tried this but it is not based only on the "0" value.

```
$3 != p1 { print p0 $0 }
{ p1 = $3; p0 = $0 ORS }
END { printf "%s", p0 }

awk -f test.awk test.txt

chr1    1       1
chr1    1       1
chr1    2       5
chr1    2       5
chr1    3       0
chr1    5       0
chr1    6       3
chr1    6       3
chr1    7       4
chr1    7       4
chr1    8       0
chr1    9       0
chr1    10      6
chr1    10      6
```

Any help?

Comment: If there were a single line ending 0 (with a non zero line before and after) should it appear twice in the output (being the first and last zero line in that block) or should it appear only once in the output?

Comment: I edited my post. If it appears twice, it should be better.

Comment: Why is `"chr1    4       0"` not in your output list? It it is supposed to be, then simply `awk '$NF == 0' file` will do.

Comment: Because I want the first and last line of the range when the 3rd column value is 0. Not all the lines where $NF==0

Comment: When posting code you got from elsewhere (i.e. my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/31820666/1745001), it'd good to provide a reference to where you got it form so we have some context to help us understand why you're using that code. I think one of my other answers, https://stackoverflow.com/a/26806036/1745001, would have been a better starting point for you given [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75667878/print-first-and-last-matching-0-in-column/75668283#comment133492973_75668258).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `awk` script saves field 3 and field 0 (the whole line) of each current line so it can be used to determine whether a $3=0 line is the first, last, or internal to a run of lines with zero in field 3.

It's set out in blocks in an awk file to make it more easily understood. If an isolated line contains zero in field three, it occurs in the output twice as it is both a starting and ending zero line.

### The awk file named `zeroblocks.awk`

```
BEGIN {last3=1; lastline="";}

{
  if ($3==0){
    if (last3 != 0) {
      print $0;
    }
  } else if (last3 == 0) {
           print lastline;
         }

  last3 = $3;
  lastline = $0;
}


END {
if (last3 == 0) {print lastline}
}
```

### tested on data in file named zeroData.txt

```
chr1    1       1
chr1    2       5
chr1    3       0
chr1    4       0
chr1    5       0
chr1    6       3
chr1    7       4
chr1    8       0
chr1    9       0
chr1    10      6
chr1    11      0
chr1    12      7
chr1    13      8
chr1    14      0
chr1    15      0
chr1    16      0
chr1    17      2
chr1    18      0
```

### using the command:

```
awk -f zeroblocks.awk zeroData.txt
```

### output

```
chr1    3       0
chr1    5       0
chr1    8       0
chr1    9       0
chr1    11      0
chr1    11      0
chr1    14      0
chr1    16      0
chr1    18      0
chr1    18      0
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding a standalone row to OP's input:

```
$ cat test.txt
chr1    1       1
chr1    2       5
chr1    3       0     # print first 0
chr1    4       0
chr1    5       0     # print last 0
chr1    6       3
chr1    7       4
chr1    8       0     # print first 0
chr1    9       0     # print last 0
chr1    10      6
chr3    222     0     # print first/last 0 (ie, standalone)
chr4    888     1
```

**NOTE:** comments added for clarification; file does not contain comments

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
function print_prev() {
   if (prevline) print prevline
   prevline=""
}
$3!=0 { print_prev() }
$3==0 { if (prev3!=$3) print
        else prevline=$0        # remove the "else" to print a standalone line twice
      }
      { prev3=$3 }
END   { print_prev() }
' test.txt
```

This generates:

```
chr1    3       0
chr1    5       0
chr1    8       0
chr1    9       0
chr3    222     0
```

When we remove the `else` (leaving `if(prev3!=$3) print; prevline=$0`) this generates:

```
chr1    3       0
chr1    5       0
chr1    8       0
chr1    9       0
chr3    222     0
chr3    222     0
```

Comment: Thanks, it works on my side. Is there a way to print twice the unique 0 line (with a non zero line before and after) ?

Comment: so, you want the `chr3 222 0` line to show up twice? please update the question with the additional input rows, also update the expected output; point being ... make sure the question demonstrates the different scenarios so that people don't have to read through comments to get the whole picture

Comment: Yes if possible ?

Comment: Your crystal ball is working better than mine today, I looked past the first/last `0` scenario `:)`

Comment: @Paillou answer updated; just need to remove the `else` to print a standalone twice

Answer (score 0):

With your shown samples only, please try following `awk` code.

```
awk '
$NF==0 &&  first{ last=$0 }
$NF==0 && !first{
  first=$0
  next
}
$NF!=0 && first{
  if(last){
    print first ORS last
  }
  else{
    print first
  }
  first=last=""
}
'  Input_file
```